# Не могу получить ошибку с сервера

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios, backend

Только начинаю изучать бекенд, я специализируюсь на реакте

Я делаю на сервере регистрацию и сделал проверку, если такой пользователь существует вернуть ошибку с сообщением

```
const {username, password} = req.body
const candidate = await Users.findOne({username})

if(candidate){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Пользователь с таким именеем существует'})
}
```

Когда регистрируюсь на фронте мне выдает ошибку, но не получается получить сообщение

```
try {
   await instance.post('/register', {username, password}).then(res => res.data).catch(err => console.log(err.data))
} catch (error) {
    alert(error)
}
```

В Network приходит это сообщение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но *err.data* выдает *undefined*

Или наверное я что-то в бекенде не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте на фронте так получить ошибку:

```
.catch(err => console.log(err.response.data))
```

Я бы порекомендовал использовать либо `async/await` + `.catch()`, либо `async/await` + `try/catch`. А не все вместе.

Comment: Получил сообщение спасибо. Хорошо возьму на заметку